# How to log into a different file per Task with log4net?

Tags: c#, log4net

I developed an application which runs several tasks in parallel. In order to make the logfiles of the application easier to read, I want each of those tasks to log into its own log file via log4net.
Additionally, I also want everything that is logged outside of the tasks to be logged into a "Main" log file so I have one log file per task and also one log file that contains everything except what is being logged inside the tasks.
This is my current log4net configuration xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
   <configSections>
      <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
   </configSections>
   <log4net>
      <appender name="MainRollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
         <filter type="log4net.Filter.PropertyFilter">
            <key value="LogicName" />
            <regexToMatch value="^(?!Main$).*$" />
            <acceptOnMatch value="false" />
         </filter>
         <param name="File" value="C:\Temp\Test\Main.log" />
         <appendToFile value="true" />
         <rollingStyle value="Size" />
         <maxSizeRollBackups value="100" />
         <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
         <staticLogFileName value="true" />
         <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
         <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
         <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout, log4net">
            <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger: %message%newline" />
         </layout>
      </appender>
      <appender name="TaskRollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
         <filter type="log4net.Filter.PropertyFilter">
            <key value="LogicName" />
            <regexToMatch value="^(?!Main$).*$" />
         </filter>
         <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter" />
         <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="C:\Temp\Test\%property{LogicName}.log" />
         <appendToFile value="true" />
         <rollingStyle value="Size" />
         <maxSizeRollBackups value="100" />
         <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
         <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
         <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
         <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout, log4net">
            <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger: %message%newline" />
         </layout>
      </appender>
      <root>
         <level value="ALL" />
         <appender-ref ref="MainRollingLogFileAppender" />
         <appender-ref ref="LogicRollingLogFileAppender" />
      </root>
   </log4net>
</configuration>
```

When creating the individual tasks I immediately run this line of code to set the current logic name for this task (`logicName` contains the name of the logic executed in the current task):

```
log4net.LogicalThreadContext.Properties["LogicName"] = logicName;
```

Each of the tasks gets started like this:

```
Task.Run(async () =>
{
    await executeLogic(); // The first line in this function sets the logicName in the LogicalThreadContext
}, cancellationToken);
```

Sadly, all this does is create a `Main.log` file which stays empty while the application is running and a `(null).log` file which contains all of the application logs.
Ideally, I want everything that does not have a `LogicName` specified in the LogicalThreadContext to automatically be logged in the main logfile.
How does my log4net configuration have to look like to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since each `RollingFileAppender` has a handle to a file, it is impossible to dynamically create new file with the same appender. You cannot use configuration file in this case - you have to programmatically create new appender each time you create new `Thread`.

Here is an example how you can achieve that. All logs from `Main` are going to `Main.log`, each thread has its own log file.

```
using log4net;
using log4net.Appender;
using log4net.Config;
using log4net.Filter;
using log4net.Layout;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AppenderTest
{
    static class Program
    {
        static ILog log;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ConfigureAppender("Main");

            log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program));

            log.Info("Starting from Main!");

            Task task1 = Task.Run(() => NewThread("LogicName1"));

            log.Info("Hello from Main!");

            Task task2 = Task.Run(() => NewThread("LogicName2"));

            log.Info("Hello again from Main!");

            Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);

            log.Info("Still from Main!");
        }

        public static void NewThread(string name)
        {
            ConfigureAppender(name);

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(50);

                log.Info($"Loop index {i}");
            }
        }

        private static void ConfigureAppender(string name)
        {
            RollingFileAppender appender = new RollingFileAppender
            {
                Name = $"{name}Appender",
                File = $"{name}.log"
            };

            PatternLayout layout = new PatternLayout
            {
                ConversionPattern = "%date{hh:mm:ss.fff} %level %thread %logger %property{LogicName} - %message%newline"
            };

            layout.ActivateOptions();

            appender.Layout = layout;

            PropertyFilter filter = new PropertyFilter
            {
                Key = "LogicName",
                StringToMatch = name,
                AcceptOnMatch = true
            };

            filter.ActivateOptions();

            appender.AddFilter(filter);
            appender.AddFilter(new DenyAllFilter());

            appender.ActivateOptions();

            LogicalThreadContext.Properties["LogicName"] = name;

            BasicConfigurator.Configure(appender);
        }
    }
}
```